# Retraining the Inception V3 Model for Machine Learning

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm doing image classification with two classes using the Inception V3 model. Since I'm using two new classes(Normal and Abnormal) I'm freezing the top layers of the Inception V3 model and replacing it with my own.

```
base_model = keras.applications.InceptionV3(
        weights ='imagenet',
        include_top=False, 
        input_shape = (img_width,img_height,3))

#Classifier Model ontop of Convolutional Model
model_top = keras.models.Sequential()
model_top.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:], data_format=None)),
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dense(400,activation='relu'))
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation = 'sigmoid'))
model = keras.models.Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = model_top(base_model.output))
```

Is freezing the convolutional layers this way in Inception V3 necessary for training?

```
#freeze the convolutional layers of InceptionV3
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(
                    lr=0.00002,
                    beta_1=0.9,
                    beta_2=0.999,
                    epsilon=1e-08),
                    loss='binary_crossentropy',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: It's not necessary, but convenient and certainly advisable & recommended...

Answer (score 2):

**No**, it is **not necessary** to freeze the first layers of a CNN; you can just initialize the weights from a pre-trained model. However, in most cases it is **recommended** to freeze them as the features they can extract are *generic* enough to help in any image-related task and doing so can speed up the training process.

That being said, you should experiment a bit with the **number** of layers you want to freeze. Allowing the latter layers of your `base_model` to *fine-tune* on your task could improve performance. You can think of it like a hyper-parameter of your model. Say you want to freeze *only* the first 30 layers:

```
for layer in model.layers[:30]:
    layer.trainable = False
```